# iPhone App recently uploaded to App Store crashes on launch

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, app-store

I uploaded the new version of my iPhone App into the App Store. And it got released last day. The problem is App is crashing on the very launch. I got the crash log as follows. Any help will be really appreciable.

Here is my crash log,

```
Incident Identifier: 7868F4D2-C13E-4D97-995F-A69F85022F8C
CrashReporter Key:   113c3b5b073754be0c5c2b9758ca6b6d2afa09e6
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         Ph_PDF [623]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/85E5F394-9006-431D-8F40-4780112F0343/Ph_PDF.app/Ph_PDF
Identifier:      Ph_PDF
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-11-05 11:13:04.916 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x96f6c04c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37ff9fbc objc_msgSend + 16
1   Ph_PDF                          0x000178ae 0x1000 + 92334
2   UIKit                           0x32e2c7e4 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1180
3   UIKit                           0x32e263b6 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 390
4   UIKit                           0x32df491a -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1010
5   UIKit                           0x32df43b8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48
6   UIKit                           0x32df3d26 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5802
7   GraphicsServices                0x339dfe0c PurpleEventCallback + 876
8   CoreFoundation                  0x30e2e54c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30e2e4ee __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30e2d33c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
11  CoreFoundation                  0x30db04d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
12  CoreFoundation                  0x30db039e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
13  UIKit                           0x32e25450 -[UIApplication _run] + 544
14  UIKit                           0x32e2273c UIApplicationMain + 1084
15  Ph_PDF                          0x0000250c 0x1000 + 5388
16  Ph_PDF                          0x000024c0 0x1000 + 5312
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i found out the problem. As i was migrated to the new XCode i updated the Google Analytics Library to the new version which needs to support the armv7s architecture. It works fine in the new XCode. But i uploaded the binary from the old Mac which have XCode 3.2.5. When i am building it gives no error. But when the app is working in the device it crashes. I reverted the google analytics library to the older version and the problem got solved.

Thanks for your support guys..:)

Answer (score 1):

this is objc_msgSend, you are calling method on object that doesn't respond to respective selector...

maybe deprecated method that is no longer included in SDK or specified iOS version, maybe you forgot to link against specific library for release version?

Have you tested your app against all iOS versions that your app claims to support?

Comment: i had one libpng crush warning...is that make any problem?

Comment: any warning could cause problems, but I suppose these are not called at this stage. Can you run your code in debugger to reproduce bug?

Comment: But this problem i can't reproduce in debug or distribution builds...The image for splash screen is in size 320 x 460. Do that make any problem? That's what i am getting as libpng crush warning..

Comment: how did you manage to upload that to the AppStore anyway? I belive that libpng is not available on the device. You are not allowed to use external dynamic lib, so maybe you should make the 320x480 image and get rid of libpng or include libpng source code into the project.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be using Core Data by any chance and modified your Core Data entity structure?

If you can provide some insight on what sort of technology your app uses and also what you changed since last working version on the app store, that would help.

Answer (score 1):

The png crush may cause the app to crash in some situations. Thats because when the app is not able to get the image correctly for displaying, it will crash. I think in your case, the app is crashing on the startup. Please check your splash screen image first.

Comment: OMG!!! You are right my splash screen image is showing a warning in the xcode since its 320 x 460. But Correcting that not helped me to solve the crash. Crash is still there.